# How to select Group By groups which contain a specific value?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of orders which follows the below format:

```
╔══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦═══════╦══════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ Order ID ║ Subtotal ║ Shipping ║ Total ║ Product Name ║ Product Price ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1        ║ 30       ║ 5        ║ 35    ║ Apple        ║ 10            ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1        ║          ║          ║       ║ Banana       ║ 10            ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1        ║          ║          ║       ║ Coffee       ║ 10            ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2        ║ 30       ║ 5        ║ 35    ║ Peach        ║ 20            ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2        ║          ║          ║       ║ Banana       ║ 10            ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 3        ║ 20       ║ 3        ║ 23    ║ Peach        ║ 20            ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 4        ║ 40       ║ 10       ║ 50    ║ Apple        ║ 10            ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 4        ║          ║          ║       ║ Coffee       ║ 10            ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 4        ║          ║          ║       ║ Peach        ║ 20            ║
╚══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩═══════╩══════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

All order numbers come as totals - subtotal and shipping with the lines below blank.

I am trying to look into the sales of a specific product.

For example I'd like to have a query which selects all orders which contain "Banana" and also returns the subtotal, shipping and total for the order as well as the product price (which are sometimes not on the same line):

I.e. it'd return this:

```
╔══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦═══════╦══════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ Order ID ║ Subtotal ║ Shipping ║ Total ║ Product Name ║ Product Price ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1        ║ 30       ║ 5        ║ 35    ║ Banana       ║ 10            ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2        ║ 30       ║ 5        ║ 35    ║ Banana       ║ 10            ║
╚══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩═══════╩══════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Comment: Yeah obviously not ideal, but sadly this is the platform export I have on hand. This is what I have to work with, but thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It's a weird order where you have no idea what the quantities are for named items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the table to itself:

```
select 
  b.`Order ID`,
  max(s.Subtotal) as 'Subtotal',
  max(s.Shipping) as 'Shipping',
  max(s.Total) as 'Total',
  b.`Product Name`,
  b.`Product Price`
from orders b
  join orders s on s.`Order ID`=b.`Order ID`
where b.`Product Name`='Banana'
group by 
  b.`Order ID`, 
  b.`Product Name`,
  b.`Product Price`
```

See a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=180aa00f5132388c02647414c7bab613).

Comment: This works perfectly, but can you help me understand how it works? So we join both tables, but only those fields where Product Name matches our criteria?

Comment: First you find out which orders have Bananas in them. Then you join the orders with the same orders-table to get the Subtotal+Shipping+Total values from the total row.